# Bjoern WSGI server unix socket permissions

Tags: python, bjoern

Is there a way to force `UID`/`permissions` on the unix socket created by `Bjoern` WSGI server?

By default it creates socket with the following permissions:

```
srwxr-xr-x
```

I need to change that to:

```
srwxrw-rw-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to pass to [Bjoern](https://github.com/jonashaag/bjoern) a Python socket object, therefore one can change socket permissions as needed. The following did the trick for me:

```
socket_path = sys.argv[1] or './bjoern.socket'
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX)
sock.bind(socket_path)
sock.listen(1024)
os.chmod(socket_path, 0o666)
print('## Bjoern socket path:', sock.getsockname())

try:
    bjoern.server_run(sock, wsgi_app)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os.unlink(sock.getsockname())
    sock.close()
```